# RabbitMQ: multiple queues/one (long) task at a time

Tags: python, rabbitmq

I'm using RabbitMQ to manage multiple servers executing long lasting tasks. Each server can listen to one or more queues, but each server should process only one task at a time.

Each time I start a consumer in a server, I configure it with `channel.basic_qos(prefetch_count=1)` so that only one tasks is processed for the respective queue.

Suppose we have:
 - 2 queues: task1, task2.
 - 2 servers: server1, server2.
 - Both servers *work* with task1 and task2.

If the next messages are produced at the same time:
 - messageA for tasks1
 - messageB for tasks2
 - messageC for tasks1

What I expect:
 - messageA gets processed by server1
 - messageB gets processed by server2
 . messageC stays queued until one of the servers is ready (finishes its current task).

What I actually get:
 - messageA gets processed by worker1
 - messageB gets processed by worker2
 - messageC gets processed by worker2 (WRONG)

I do not start consumers at the same time. In fact, working tasks are constantly being turned on/off in each server. Most of the time servers work with different queues (server1: tasks1, tasks2, task3; server2: tasks1, tasks5; server3: tasks2, tasks5; and so on).

How could I manage to do this?

**EDIT**
Based on Olivier's answer:
Tasks are different. Each server is able to handle some of the tasks, not all of them. A server could process only one task at a time.

I tried using exchanges with routing_keys, but I found two problems: all of the servers binded to the routing key task_i would process its tasks (I need it to be processed only once), and if there is no server binded to task_i, then its messages are dropped (I need to remain queued until some server can handle it).

Answer (score 0):

Seems from the description you provide that the issue is due to your servers connecting to multiple queues at the same time.

As your prefetch count is set to 1, a server connected to 3 queues will consume up to 3 messages even though he will only be processing one at a time (per your description of processing).

It's not clear from your question whether there is a need for multiple queues or whether you could have all tasks end up in a single queue:

- do all the servers consume all the tasks
- do you need to be able to stop the processing of certain tasks

If you need/wish to be able to "stop" the processing of certain tasks, or control the distribution of processing throughout your servers, you'll need to manage consumers in your servers to only have one active consumer at a time (otherwise you're going to block/consume some messages due to prefetch 1).

If you do not need to control the processing of the various tasks, would be far simpler to have all of the messages end up in a single queue, and single consumer to that queue setup with prefetch one for each of your servers.

Comment: Thanks for your help Olivier. As you said, being any server able to be connected to more than one queue, the problem is that it actually could process more than one task at a time. The problem I find by using a single queue is that each task is different. task1 tasks are completely different tasks than those on task2, and only a server able to handle task1 should process it (and only one). I tried using exchanges with routing_keys, but each server binded to the routing key task1 would process the task (I need it to be processed only once). I do not need to be able to stop the processing.

Comment: If you need only one server to process a given queue/task, you might be interested in defining your consumer as exclusive?

Comment: I need only one server to process each task, but there will be many servers able to handle it. I mean: messageA for tasks1 should be processed by only one server, but there could be 3 or 4 servers listening to tasks1 (any of them could be the choosen to process it).

Comment: From the logic you wish to setup, seems like you'd have an easier time performing gets for the messages, instead of using message consumers. You could then loop through the various queues, and process whichever event is available before continuing to loop. This avoid the prefetch issue you encountered (but is of course a bit heavier code side as you need to test if get returns something).

Comment: How would "performing gets for the messages instead of using message consumers" be? Can you explain a little more about it? Thanks!